# How to extend layout based on database

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to extend a layout which the folder name is retrived from database. Bellow is the code.

```
@extends('layout.'.{{ $layout->layout}}.'.main')
```

But it is not working, what is the logic behind getting layout name from database? Please let me know.

Comment: Did you try to remove the dot? just like this @extends('layout.'{{ $layout->layout}}'.main')

Comment: Yes, Still not working.

Comment: how about this @extends({{$layout->layout}}) then in the controller concat those string u want. or remove the bracket

Comment: Thank you Grald, I think that way may work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need the blade brackets {{ }}.  The brackets are short for

@extends('layout.' . $layout->layout . '.main')

I didn't test it but it should work.